# How to change textformat of many nodes at once?

Tags: drush

How to change textformat of many nodes at once,

module? drush? or script

**UPDATE** (sorry I was on the run at first edit)

I had imported hundred or more nodes I had to migrate from an old site. Did it via node_export. The new site has a textformat with same name, but defined another way so I decided all nodes should be plain text .

I websearched a bit but could not found anything. So i thought there might by a module with VBO support for that?

Comment: please elaborate more your question.

Comment: the update is relatively simple. the question is whtehter there is any difference between the two nodetypes ? fields for example ?

Answer (score 1):

In previous instances where this has happened to me, I've just updated the *_format column in the field_revision_* & field_data_* tables, flushed the Drupal cache, and things worked without issue.

For example, if you're looking to change the nodes' body format for all imported nodes of type *my_type* from *my_format* to *plain_text*, you could execute this query:

```
UPDATE field_data_body SET body_format = 'plain_text' WHERE entity_type = 'node' AND bundle = 'my_type' AND body_format = 'my_format';
UPDATE field_revision_body SET body_format = 'plain_text' WHERE entity_type = 'node' AND bundle = 'my_type' AND body_format = 'my_format';
```

**NOTE:** There's probably a better, programmatic way, than touching the database directly, but I've never seen any adverse effects from this method.